# Biding Radiobutton to gridview & again insert binded values to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am working on a project I bound the Radiobutton to grid view it works and fetch the data to GridView properly now again I want to insert the values of checked and unchecked of RadioButton to database, but doesn't work properly it pass all RadioButton as false.
    for clarifying the bellow is it code.
    from before I am thankful for your answer.

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Online_Examination_System
{
    public partial class FormAnswers : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        int count;
        ClassCommon obj = new ClassCommon();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                count = 1;
            }
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = obj.GetData("select Question from tblQuestions where QId='" + count + "'");
            gvQuestions.DataSource = dt;
            gvQuestions.DataBind();

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2 = obj.GetData("select Answer from tblAnswers where QId='" + count + "'");
            gvAnswers.DataSource = dt2;
            gvAnswers.DataBind();

        }

        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count = 1;
            if (ViewState["view"] != null)
            {
                count = Convert.ToInt16(ViewState["view"]);
            }
            ViewState["view"] = count + 1;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt = obj.GetData("select Question from tblQuestions where QId='" + ViewState["view"] + "'");
            gvQuestions.DataSource = dt;
            gvQuestions.DataBind();

            DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
            dt2 = obj.GetData("select Answer from tblAnswers where QId='" + ViewState["view"] + "'");
            gvAnswers.DataSource = dt2;
            gvAnswers.DataBind();
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < gvAnswers.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    int V;
                    RadioButton rBtnAnswer = gvAnswers.Rows[i].FindControl("rbtnSelect") as RadioButton;
                    if (rBtnAnswer.Checked)
                    {
                        V = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        V = 0;
                    }
                    Label txtAnswered = gvAnswers.Rows[i].FindControl("lblAnswer") as Label;
                    obj.ExeQuery("insert into tblResult values('" + V + "','" + txtAnswered.Text + "',Null,NULL,NULL,Null)");
                }
            }
        }
```

HTML

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="FormAnswers.aspx.cs" Inherits="Online_Examination_System.FormAnswers" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function SelectRadioButton(radio) {
                var rdBtn = document.getElementById(radio.id);
                var rdBtnList = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
                for (i = 0; i < rdBtnList.length; i++) {
                    if (rdBtnList[i].type == "radio" && rdBtnList[i].id != rdBtn.id) {
                        rdBtnList[i].checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .style1
            {
                width: 100%;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>

            <table class="auto-style1">
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvQuestions" runat="server" GridLines="None">
                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:GridView ID="gvAnswers" runat="server" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                            <Columns>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Select">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:RadioButton ID="rbtnSelect" runat="server" />
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Answer">
                                    <ItemTemplate>
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblAnswer" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Answer") %>'></asp:Label>
                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                </asp:TemplateField>
                            </Columns>

                        </asp:GridView>
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="auto-style1">
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Next" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                    </td>
                    <td>&nbsp;</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

        </div>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below will never get executed, since it inside the `!IsPostBack` condition.

```
for (int i = 1; i < gvAnswers.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    int V;

    RadioButton rBtnAnswer = gvAnswers.Rows[i].FindControl("rbtnSelect") as RadioButton;

    if (rBtnAnswer.Checked)
    {
        V = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        V = 0;
    }

    Label txtAnswered = gvAnswers.Rows[i].FindControl("lblAnswer") as Label;
    obj.ExeQuery("insert into tblResult values('" + V + "','" + txtAnswered.Text + "',Null,NULL,NULL,Null)");
}
```

All you need to do is to remove the `!IsPostBack` condition.

For more details check out [this](https://www.google.jo/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0ahUKEwiater-rZHRAhVPNFAKHTjrB3EQFggaMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.ui.page.ispostback(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNHa32Ycbb1cWcthnBguXpTw0QKRPw&sig2=h9-9mHKpbqfPXWNwYKkTVw&bvm=bv.142059868,d.d2s).